# Configure web service soap proxy settings in Eclipse

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, soap

I have a Java application that consumes one of my Web Services. I do so using a proxy class. I know for a fact that you can configure the settings for the proxy to return a `List` instead of the default `Object[]` in Visual Studio. How do I do this in Eclipse?

In Visual Studio I right click on my reference under "Service References" in the solution explorer, choose "Configure service reference" and then change the collection type from `System.Array` to `System.Collection.Generic.List`.

In Eclipse i have my `WebServiceSoapProxy.java` class but I don't know how to configure it the same way as I did in Visual Studio. How should I do this?

Comment: Have same requirement, did you get any way to do this?

Comment: Nope. I solved it by creating a new List from the Object[]. Not the most optimal solution but it solved my problem.